# Remove/Replace all whitespaces from a multi-lines string, except newline characters

Tags: python, regex, newline, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I want to remove all whitespace characters from a multi-line string using regex.
What I am looking for is something like:

```
exp = re.compile("\s-[\r\n]")
exp.sub('', text)
```

Is there a regex that does the above. Since the `text` is unicode, which has a possibility of other characters that could form the `\s` class besides `[\t\v\f \r\n]`, I cannot use `[\t\v\f ]`.

Comment: By the way - I'm no Python knowing individual, but shouldn't you use [`re.U`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.U)?

Comment: About `re.U`, I thought python used it automatically when the input text was unicode. Right now all my data is in English, so I do not know if there is any other whitespace character other than the above. I just came accross the list of characters in `\s` from the python doc. I was really trying to use the mentioned regex `[\t\v\f ]` for my needs, when the unicode question came in mind. If you know of any unicode whitespace character besides the above please let me know, and I will check if I need to use `re.U` or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this double-negative character class:

```
[^\S\r\n]
```

Example: http://rubular.com/r/t2Ahjs9UzF